# Hundreds of JSX element type 'xxx' is not a constructor function for JSX elements?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I inherited a project in React (with Redux and Antd), ASP.NET, and C# and I am getting literally hundreds of errors of the following kind:

> TS2605    (TS) JSX element type 'xxx' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.

The programmers who gave me the code claim that they do not "have" these errors (so they might be just ignoring them since the code compiles anyhow). I figured that it might have to do with my React version (I have the newest). Downgrading was suggested by different resources (see below) as work-around, but this is not an option for me.

I tested different ways of importing React, but that did not reduce the number of errors. Here one example where I see red underlined code in my Visual Studio (Professional 2017):

```
import * as React from "react";
// ... 
import { DatePicker } from "antd"; // I also load other things from antd
const { MonthPicker } = DatePicker;
// ... 
<MonthPicker 
     format="MMMM YYYY"
      style={{ width: 150 }}
      placeholder="Date"
      onChange={(e) => { this.handleSelectorChange("Date", e) }}
     value={this.props.selectedDate !== null ? moment(this.props.selectedDate) : null}
/>
```

In other words, the error occurs both for user defined elements `xxx` as well as for standard ones like `MonthPicker`. **What does the error exactly mean and how do I fix it?**

The interesting thing is that the project runs anyhow, although the errors occur.

#### EDIT: Background information

My `package.json` reads

```
^{
  "version": "1.3.3.7",
  "name": "myProject.UI",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "npm audit": "npm audit",
    "webpack": "webpack -w",
    "webpack-prod": "webpack -p",
    "version": "node --version"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^2.10.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "download": "^6.2.5",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "15.5.3",
    "react-dom": "15.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.14.8",
    "reselect": "^3.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "15.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.23",
    "@types/react-redux": "^4.4.40",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.3",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

#### Resources

- [JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679118/jsx-element-type-element-is-not-a-constructor-function-for-jsx-elements)
- [JSX element type 'xxx' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Property 'yyy' is protected in type 'xxx' but public in type 'ElementClass'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970097/jsx-element-type-xxx-is-not-a-constructor-function-for-jsx-elements-property)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter/issues/45

**Edit as of 2019-09-16:** More resources

- https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/4892
- [JSX element type 'CounterDisplay' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Types of property 'refs' are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720532/jsx-element-type-counterdisplay-is-not-a-constructor-function-for-jsx-elements)

Comment: Sounds like these are VSCode warnings. If you try another IDE do you get the same errors?

Comment: What is the type definition of the components?

Comment: @Ferrybig: I guess, there is not a single definition, but many leading to that error. Example: `class Component<P, S> implements ComponentLifecycle<P, S> {` in `myProject.UI\node_modules\@types\react\index.d.t` leads to `TS2559 (TS) Type 'Component<P, S>' has no properties in common with type 'ComponentLifecycle<P, S>'.`

Comment: I'm missing quite a few dependencies in your `package.json`. For example the version of TypeScript itself but I also don't see any `@types` packages. Maybe those are in `devDependencies`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter: Thanks (again). I added both `tsconfig.json` and `package.json`.

Comment: It is possible due to different versions of @type/react and react itself. remove package.lock or yarn.lock and node_modules, make it same version and try again.

Comment: @m.akbari I did remove the  `package.lock`, and did a complete update, but that did not help. What exact changes within `package.json` do you suggest? Maybe you could post an answer?

Comment: react version and @type/react should have same version. what version you intend to use? (latest or any specific version? ) Nevertheless, because you do not have ^ character in front of the versions, packages will not update.

Comment: @m.akbari Ideally, the latest version should be ok. I did not know about the caret symbol, thanks for that. Do you have any idea about [antd] and its requirements?

Comment: Also, check other related library version are compatible with the react version you intend to use (react-redux, react-router)

Comment: Fastest way, to remove all the versions and replaces it with *. This will automatically update all the packages to their latest. (make sure your code does not break on updating packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting them everywhere on code that was working before, it's probably a dependency issue.  I'd try re-installing everything by deleting `node_modules` and running `yarn install` or `npm install` (depending on which package manager you are using). Also, try updating your `react`, `react-dom`, `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` packages to the most recent version, e.g. with

```
npm install --save @types/react-select -D
```

Comment: To be specific: The code is running both in debug and production mode, although it is an error, so I am pretty sure that is not a dependency issue. A `npm install` did not solve it.

Comment: Also, can you post an example of a component declaration that is throwing one of these errors?

Comment: I edited the post and included an extract of `package.json`. Although it says that project contains `redux-dom`, I have not seen it being imported.
The `MonthPicker` is an **antd** component, see https://ant.design/components/date-picker/

Comment: I got 200+ errors removed using your method (twice in a row, the first time, nothing happened). Nevertheless there are *some* sticky ones, in particular some `<Link>`-components (from `react-router-dom').

Comment: Glad I could help! A lot of packages, ```react-router-dom``` being one of them, have their own published typedef packages, so installing ```@types/react-router-dom``` should help. Also note that it's best to add ```@types``` packages as development dependencies so they don't take up unnecessary space in your production builds, as TS is transpiled to regular JS which cannot use them.  Just add the ```-D``` flag to your install commands.

Answer (score 0):

You might try removing `package.lock.json` and then running `npm i`. This might fix the issue.

Comment: @sarathantony: Yes, I tried removing `package.lock`  and updating, but that did not solve the issue.